# jQuery modal box like Mac alert

Tags: jquery, html, plugins, modal-dialog

How do I make a modal dialog slide in from the top of the browser like mac?

All the plugins I look at don't have this option.

Comment: Did you try something? Or do you want someone here to write a plugin for you?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a plugin available that I don't know about, or if there's a simple way to do it. Not looking for hand-outs. :)

Comment: hah ok, I'm not aware of one, but may be jquery tools' overlay could be used to create such a thing...

Comment: It's nothing hard to code. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [ModalBox](http://okonet.ru/projects/modalbox/) does what you're looking for.

Comment: Everyone makes mistakes. :) And now that you fixed yours, +1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question (I don't have a mac). But jqueryUI is pretty light and really easy to use.
I think a modal dialog with a slide animation might be all you need.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Answer (score 0):

**[jGrowl](http://stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html)** is an awesome plug-in.  It has quite a few options that make it configurable. Give it a whirl.

From their website:

> jGrowl is a nifty little jQuery
>   library that creates unobtrusive
>   messages in the browser. It works in a
>   similar way to Growl on Mac OS X.